# How to automate renaming columns in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data-frame with multiple columns. I want to rename their columns as "col_1", "col_2" as so on. Could anyone suggest a method to do that.

The number of columns is large, so I cannot rename each explicitly.

Edit:

Or is there a way to append "col" to each column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to rename the columns as "col_1", "col_2",etc.

```
df.columns = ['col_' + ind for ind in range(1,len(df.columns)+1)]
```

Here's how to append 'col' to every column name.

```
df.columns = [column + 'col' for column in df.columns]
```